# Fedora: No module named 'ZODB' in Python 3

Tags: python, zodb

How can I install ZODB for Python 3? I installed python-ZODB3 in Fedora, but I can use ZODB only in Python 2:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.5 (default, Sep 25 2014, 13:57:38) 
[GCC 4.8.3 20140911 (Red Hat 4.8.3-7)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import ZODB
>>> quit()
$ python3
Python 3.3.2 (default, Jun 30 2014, 17:20:03) 
[GCC 4.8.3 20140624 (Red Hat 4.8.3-1)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import ZODB
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.3/code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'ZODB'
```

Which package am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, the Fedora name for Python package `foo` for Python 3.x is `python3-foo`, not `python-foo3`.

In particular, `python-ZODB3` is the Python 2.x package for ZODB3. ([`ZODB3`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ZODB3/3.11.0) is the obsolete version 3 of [`ZODB`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ZODB), still provided for backward compatibility.) Both the old 3.x and new 4.x versions of ZODB work for both Python 2.x and 3.x; that means there are (at least potentially) packages named `python-ZODB` (ZODB 4.x for Python 2.x), `python3-ZODB` (4.x for 3.x), `python-ZODB3` (3.x for 2.x), and `python3-ZODB3` (3.x for 3.x). It's the second one you want, not the third.

I can't guarantee that your Fedora version and repos have a `python3-ZODB` RPM, but from a quick search, I found [this](http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3?stat=3&search=python3-ZODB), so at least some Fedora-based systems have one.

If there's not a Fedora RPM for that, you can probably install it via [`pip`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/), something like `pip3 install ZODB`.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer, I accepted it because it led me to the solution, but I haven't found packages named `python3-ZODB*` in my repositories (I use Fedora 20). I have finally found that the correct sentence is `pip-3.3 install ZODB`.

Comment: Just for the record, in Korora (a spin of Fedora) I had to run `sudo yum install python3-devel` first and then `sudo easy_install-3.3 ZODB`.

Comment: @czayas: You really shouldn't be using `easy_install` in general. (There are good reasons in some cases, but if you don't know you have such a reason, you don't have one.) I'm pretty sure there's a `python3-pip` package you can install; if not, you can install it manually.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I didn't know there were big differences between the two, I always preferred `pip` over `easy_install` only because the command is shorter ;-)